# How to merge /data and /sdcard on Android 4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, mount, partitions, internal-sd

Is it possible to use two partitions as one storage on a MediaTek device?

AFAIK, it is already implemented in Samsung Galaxy S III, may be.

Comment: Which device are you talking about? Have you checked if there is a custom ROM that already does what you want (or at least has a installation manual that covers this step)? Doing this manually is not that simple...

Comment: @Robert I am talking about an Mediatek phone based on android 4.4 and want to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Not very large number of [physical primary only](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example#android_5_x_physical) devices were shipped with separate `/sdcard` partition (with attribute `removable="false"`) in transition phase from UMS to MTP. Most of those were shipped with ICS or JB, a few got updated to KK. Then mostly vendors moved to the dominant concept of [emulation](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) on `/data/media/0`. See [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526) for more details.

You can take risk to paly with partition table in order to merge both partitions: `/data` and `/sdcard` (depends on the layout of partitions). But how would you get a compatible ROM? In fact you'll have to develop a custom ROM from scratch, which needs modification to both; AOSP and kernel code. Particularly `vold` configurations need special upgradation as it would be looking for partition to be mounted at `/sdcard` with *(permission-less)* FAT filesystem, which is now merged to `/data` with `ext4` filesystem. Storage configuration in framework, `fstab` and `init.*.rc` files would also needed to be changed.

So the struggle required isn't worth it. And I doubt even if you would be able to get complete source code for such an old device.