# Why does my phone contain WhatsApp Images both on my SD card and in my internal storage?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I know that WhatsApp Images are saved by default on the internal storage of my phone. However, on my phone there is also a WhatsApp media file on my external SD card. This folder contains the same number of image files that is also displayed in my *Gallery* App (when I click on WhatsApp Images). The WhatsApp Images folder on my internal storage also contains way more files than the one on my SD card. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: it is a leftover from previous phone where you have used the same microSD card

Comment: Android version? Device? ROM? On stock Android apps cannot have direct write access to external SD card except to private directories. And I don't think WhatsApp uses Storage Access Framework. Explained here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526. Make sure by downloading new images if those are saved to external SD card. What's the path of external SD card where you see WhatsApp Images directory?