# Why there's an "Android" folder in my phone's storage?

Tags: sd-card

I'm just wanted to know why there's an Android folder. As we all know that the data which apps stores for itself stores in root directory which is "data/data" but why there's an Android folder? Please let me know.

Comment: this is basically used for unimportant data. for example spotify caches huge amount of data in that directory

Comment: Or used for data, the device owner is supposed to have access to from a PC via USB/MTP.

Comment: `Android` folder includes apps' private directories in public/shared storage. Sounds weird? See details in [Android's Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526).

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I got my answer