# prevent android device from creating folders on otg storage

Tags: root-access, storage, usb-on-the-go

I know similar questions have been asked, but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

Whenever I connect a storage device to my phone, it creates the following folders on that device:

- Alarms
- Audiobooks
- Documents
- LOST.DIR
- Music
- Pictures
- Ringtones
- Android
- DCIM
- Download
- Movies
- Notifications
- Podcasts

I need none of these. Is there a way to not have this happen every time? Possibly a magisk module or something.

Edit:

Additional information:

Rom: oxygen os 11

Device: OnePlus Nord CE

Comment: I would assume that this is a bug of your device (the details about hardware. ROM, Android version is missing in your question). It seems like it misinterprets the OTG device as internal storage. On my devices only the `LOST.DIR` is created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop apps writing to "Android" folder on the SD card?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/214288/how-to-stop-apps-writing-to-android-folder-on-the-sd-card)

Comment: @iHnR - did you figure this out? Have same issue with LineageOS 18.1 (Android 11).