# What type of data is excluded from the "media only" file permission in Android 12?

Tags: file-system, permissions, file-permissions, android-12

Starting from Android 11, there are 2 levels of file access permission, i.e., "files, media, and everything" permission and "media only" permission.

What is the difference between the two, and what is excluded from the "media only" permission?

Comment: Dupe of [Difference between "manage all files" and "access media only"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245525/44325) (but not yet answered properly).

Comment: @AndrewT. I have already seen that post, but it doesn't have a good answer, that's why I posted another question

Comment: Understood, that's why this hasn't been closed as a duplicate yet. It's just no one has posted an answer while the info/references/sources are already there in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer this question, may be with the combined experience of the community we can verify if the following is correct:

According to [media store documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media_store) there are four different media categories:

> - Images, including photographs and screenshots, which are stored in the `DCIM/` and `Pictures/` directories. The system adds these files to the MediaStore.Images table.
> - Videos, which are stored in the `DCIM/`, `Movies/`, and `Pictures/` directories.
> - Audio files, which are stored in the `Alarms/`, `Audiobooks/`, `Music/`, `Notifications/`, `Podcasts/`, and `Ringtones/` directories. Additionally, the system recognizes audio playlists that are in the `Music/` or `Movies/` directories, as well as voice recordings that are in the `Recordings/` directory.
> - Downloaded files, which are stored in the `Download/` directory.

To my understanding the first three media types should be included in "media only" category. Not sure about the Downloade files type.